# Android Glide old images are loaded on scroll

Tags: android, image, gridview, android-glide

I'm using Glide and I download and display all images in my Gridview. But I have a problem when I'm scrolling in my gridview during the download. Glide load the previous images and replace them by the newest but it looks like a lag.

How can I do to load nothing if the image isn't loaded ? I had the same problem with picasso and to fix it I had set this code `imageView.setImageDrawable(null);` but with Glide this doesn't work.

**Adapter getView**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view;
    final ImageView imageView;
    final TextView legend;

    // Soft display
    if(convertView == null){
        view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.thumbnail_gallery, parent, false);
    }else{
        view = convertView;
    }

    // Get layout item (Image and Legend)
    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_thumbnail);
    legend = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_thumb);

    // Do not display old images
    imageView.setImageDrawable(null);

    // Get the file path
    final File file = new File(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), mPInfoList.get(position).getFilename());
    mToSave = !file.exists();

    // Get the download path image
    String pic = Globals.SERVER_NAME+Globals
                        .ACCOUNT_SERVER_PATH+mPInfoList
                        .get(position).getFolderPath()+"/"+
                        VgzTools.addSuffix(mPInfoList.get(position).getFilename(), "-thumb");

    // Check file exist
    if(!file.exists()){

        // Create a Simple Target for Glide
        SimpleTarget<Bitmap> simpleTarget = new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(final Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
                // Thread to save the image
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            // Image saving
                            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            resource.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutput);
                            fileOutput.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

                imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                // Set the legend
                if (mPInfoList.get(position).getFilename() != null) {
                    legend.setText(mPInfoList.get(position).getLegend());
                }
            }
        };

        // File doesn't exist Save image
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(pic)
                .asBitmap()
                .into(simpleTarget);

        mToSave = true;
    }else{
        // File exist then display it
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(file)
                .into(imageView);
        mToSave = false;
    }

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't start a load into the imageView, call `Glide#clear()` on it. Your last if/else statement should look like this:

```
if (!file.exists()) {
    Glide.clear(imageView);
    // New thread etc.
} else {
    // File exist then display it
    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(file)
            .into(imageView);
    mToSave = false;
}
```